# How big an object should I build on Earth so that it is visible from space?

Tags: science-based, space

I want to build a big structure that will be visible from space. A object would need to be very large, maybe kilometers across, to be *visible* from, let's say, the ISS (which orbits at an average height of 413 km above Earth).

How big would I have to build a non-light-emitting object, so that it is visible from space (the ISS) bare-eye?

Comment: Eee.... wait... why is this off-topic?

Comment: Why is this on-topic, really? What it has to do with building a world? not my vtc, but I kinda sympathize.

Comment: @Mołot I edited my question; Is it OK now?

Comment: @Mołot how it is not on-topic - he likes to have realistic sizes to spot alien buildings, or whatever. sure it could be also asked elsewhere, but that do not makes questions off-topic here

Comment: @MolbOrg as I've said, it's not my vote to close on this question.

Comment: @Mołot me neither, although do not find that question super exciting to upvote, although answer is kinda good, so op is even atm. Do not know which refinement could help this question to look better. Wished to replay to point which you wrote, not to you personally, because I clearly see why this point could bother others. If there is public concern there should be public answer to concerns - persons who have narrated/wrote those concerns are not important, they are just people projecting others thoughts.

Comment: @MolbOrg *"Do not know which refinement could help this question to look better."* - well, description of downvote has "lack of research effort", and this topic is discussed on so many places on the Internet, like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-made_structures_visible_from_space). Also, putting ISS as designated height is hardly useful - fictional aliens might require different (probably greater) distances. Last but not least, most man-made structures emit light. What's the woldbuilding use of excluding this factor?

Comment: @Mołot no needs to exclude, humans over alien planet, where all aliens are dead, nothing works and far far away from home looking for return. As you might see he had answer he wished to post, and OP made question for it, because he had an answer. That's why Q looks like lack of research, would be that research shown would be no answer and no question. Valid reason to close should be is that dup question or not here no WB, if not, op should accept own answer, and we should forget about it and hope it will be useful for someone, for something, sometime. Yhea not super situation, only op had fun.

Comment: @MolbOrg I'm not saying it's terrible question, I'm just sharing some ideas for improvement. Also, I could bet that voters didn't really care that it's self-answered. Most of the time, in communities I was active in, they didn't.This requires some caution with self-answered questions, true. But should votes on question (both close/reopen and up/down) depend on answers? I don't think so.

Comment: This question is the subject of a [meta] discussion: [Looking for some constructive criticism](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3972/29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest (circular) object that is *possible* to **see** from space would have to have at least (bare minimum):

### cca. 120 meters

in diameter. But this would work only if the object was **distinguishable** from the terrain around and the conditions were perfect. It would have to be in a unnatural color - red, for example - and may have to be a strong light source (the ISS and most stars are visible from Earth only because they shine really bright), but making your object shine would be a "cheat", as you said.

**The maths:**

An average man's eye can distinguish objects that cover up more than about $0.0165$ or $\frac{1}{60}$ degrees. If we define $x$ as the minimal size, we get this image:

[image: This is an image description]

If we cut it down, we get:

[image: This is also an image description]

That means that $\tan(0.00825°) \approx \frac{\frac{x}{2}}{413}$ and from that we can get that:

$x \approx 2×413×0.000144 \approx 0.120km$

Enough math, let's go real: An object would have to be **much** bigger than 120m in order to be visible from space. For example, the biggest pyramid of Giza takes up 440×440m up, but has the same color as it's surroundings, thus being "invisible" from space. If people manage to color the pyramid(s) red or brown or a similar visible colors, they would be visible.

---

#### [Man-made structures visible from space bare-eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-made_structures_visible_from_space):

- [Almeria greenhouses in Spain](http://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/08/the-greenhouses-of-almeria.html) (200 square kilometers):

[image: Another image description]

- [Bingham Canyon Mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_Canyon_Mine) (15 square kilometers):

[image: The last image description]

Comment: Just for comparison: a 120m object 413km away would be as visible as a 1.2mm object placed 4.13m away. That's in the very limit of my eyesight ability. With such an object you will be able to see a point, in the best case. If you want to see some detail, you will need a bigger object.

Comment: I'm sure there are also effects due to atmospheric effects to consider.  Turbulence in the troposphere would likely make your resolution much worse than the ideal case.

Comment: It doesn't need to be 120m diameter. It needs to be large enough to cause an observable colour or intensity change averaged out over a patch this size. In particular, a road (black or grey) across dense vegetation (green) will be noticed even if it is considerably less than 120m wide.

Comment: Further to my last, this means that a strong light source will be seen even if tiny,  though you will detect only it's presence not its size.